# Making subprocess call use a generated file name

Tags: python, subprocess

So I have a python script that generates a file name based on the time. Then I am trying to `cat` some data into that file name. However, it seems that I cannot pass it in or something.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
fileName = "parsedOn_"+strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S", gmtime())+".csv"
subprocess.call(['cat' + 'xaa' + '>' + fileName])
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "parseCSV.py", line 96, in <module>
subprocess.call(['cat' + 'xaa' + '>' + finalFile1])
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 444, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas if what I'm trying to do is possible with subprocess at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in

```
subprocess.call(['cat' + 'xaa' + '>' + fileName])
```

First of all, you're missing spaces (if you wanted to use a string), or commas (if you wanted to use a list, the preferred method). Secondly, `>` is a shell redirection, so you must execute this line in a shell, as in:

```
subprocess.call('cat xaa > ' + fileName, shell=True)
```

**But you should not do that**. Instead, use Python's native [`shutil.copyfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile):

```
shutil.copyfile('xaa', fileName)
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't even know about shutil. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy).

Sample

```
In [1]: import envoy

In [2]: r = envoy.run("cat requirements.txt")

In [3]: r.std_out
Out[3]:   'Flask==0.8\ngit+git://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-cache.git\nJinja2==2.6\ngit+git://github.com/kennethreitz/werkze ug.git\ndistribute==0.6.24\ngunicorn==0.13.4\nredis==2.4.9\nvanity==1.1.1\nwsgiref==0.1.2\n'

In [4]: print r.std_out
Flask==0.8
git+git://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-cache.git
Jinja2==2.6
git+git://github.com/kennethreitz/werkzeug.git
distribute==0.6.24
gunicorn==0.13.4
redis==2.4.9
vanity==1.1.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Edit:
    Main advantage of envoy is simplicity.

Comment: -1 Your answer has nothing to do with the question. Also, note that envoy does not support shell commands at the moment, so it's actually impossible to execute shell commands with it at the moment. Also, you fail to mention any advantages of envoy instead of subprocess, both in general as well as in this specific case.

Comment: +1: For your comment. Envoy do support shell commands, but it doesn't support redirection symbols like `>>', '<<'.